# How to use the \stretch command over two pages instead of just one

Tags: page-breaking

i try to use the \stretch command to space out pieces of text (for a concert programm) and it all works really nicely, but i have no idea how to expand this design towards two pages.
Obviously i can write a \newpage in the middle, but it feels like there should be an automated way to evenly space stuff across two pages. Thanks for any advice.

i've added a minimal example without all the macro stuff:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 12pt]{article}

\newcommand\newpiece{\vspace{\stretch{1}}}

\begin{document}

Text \hfill Text2 \par
Text \hfill Text \par
\hfill King of Denmark’s Galliard

\newpiece
John Loeillet   \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is code (eg `multicol` package) to balance text across columns but I don't know anything "out of the box" that will do that for pages, teX normally outputs page 1 before it has finished reading page 2 (memory constraints in the 1970s...)  so it has no opportunity to balance the amount of text sent to each page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\vsplit`, but for a document like this I believe that visual formatting is better.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 12pt]{article}

\newcommand\newpiece{\vspace{\stretch{1}}}

\begin{document}

Text \hfill Text2 \par
Text \hfill Text \par
\hfill King of Denmark’s Galliard

\newpiece
John Loeillet   \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\newpiece
Modified Composer \hfill Sonate No. 5 g-moll modified 

\end{document}
```

[image]